# Is "vehicle" really "транспортний засіб"? Do people say that?

Tags: вживання-слів, non-native-speaker

Both Google Translate and Duolingo translate "vehicle" as "транспортний засіб" but it just seems like a very long awkward technical-sounding phrase for a simple concept - like something I'd expect to show up on a legal form but not really in conversation. Do people use it in normal/casual speech? If yes, is it just less long and awkward to a native speaker than it seems like to me? If not, is there a different/shorter word, or do people just say car/track/motorcycle/etc instead of using the general word at all, or what?

Comment: I could be wrong, since I'm not a native English speaker, but I would think that in English vehicle also isn't used that much in every day use.

Comment: @IvoBeckers I agree it's usually not, but you'll get it in spoken conversations in official-ish contexts - e.g. I think the police say "please exit your vehicle", and I was guessing that Ukrainian police wouldn't say "транспортний засіб" in the same context.

Comment: In Ukrainian we mostly use specific names for vehicles. Like, *space vehicle (starship)* would be *зореліт* or *космічний корабель*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is *vehicle* really *транспортний засіб*?

Yes, but itʼs *канцеляризм* which means *bureaucratic jargon*, *officialese*. Also itʼs maybe calque from Russian officialese during USSR. You may find it, as you told, mostly in a legal form or somewhere from a government person.

> Do people say that?

In regular speech it is usually shorted to just *транспорт*.

> <sup>Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 10, 1979. — Стор. 232.</sup>
>
> [**ТРА́НСПОРТ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/transport), **у**, *чол*.
>
> 1. *[…]*
>
>    /  Будь-який засіб перевезення, а також сукупність таких засобів.
>
>    > *— Тобі який транспорт треба? Лінійку запрягти? Не хочеш? Ну, тоді я звелю засідлати Ластівку. Конина смирна, якраз для такого кіннотника, як ти* (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 193); *Між підводами метушився Маковейчик. Він шукав собі транспорту, щоб везти котушки з кабелем* (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 72);

But, yeah, people usually just say words like *авто, мотоцикл, вантажівка* and so on.

---

Just in case, an additional info to the previous quote. I guess, itʼs about *засіб* which can confuse someone because it has several meanings:

> <sup>Словник української мови: в 20 томах.</sup>
>
> [**ЗА́СІБ**](https://sum20ua.com/entry/search/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1), **собу**, *ч*.
>
> 1. Спосіб, якась спеціальна дія, що дає можливість здійснити що-небудь, досягти чогось.

In other words, itʼs *method* as [@fraxinus](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6955/585)ʼve wrote or how [@Andriy](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/6953/6954?noredirect=1#comment12250_6954=) may think. But it also means *а device* or  *a thing for something*:

> 2. *чого, який*. Те, що служить знаряддям у якій-небудь дії, справі.
>
>    // *перев. мн.* Механізми, пристрої і т. ін., необхідні для здійснення чого-небудь, для якоїсь діяльності.
>
>    > *Понад десяток стволів [гармат] стали поруч .. Вже не треба було розтягувати вогневі засоби на кілометри по фронту, прикриваючи найдошкульніші місця* (О. Гончар); *Чому вважається, що наш план космічного завоювання простору технічними засобами є правильний і доцільний?* (О. Бердник);

Also thereʼs a note about *транспортні засоби = транспорт*.

> (3) **За́соби пересува́ння <Тра́нспортні за́соби>** – транспорт.
>
> > *Ось ми маршируємо на пероні станції Карлівка. Чекаємо .. засобів пересування...* (О. Ковінька); *Доки десь там штабні писарі сушили собі голови, як оформляти в паперах передачу капітулюючими військами нашій армії засобів пересування.., сірі від дорожньої кіптяви піхотинці з радісним галасом накинулися на остовпілих кавалеристів* (О. Гончар); *Транспортні засоби класифікують за типом рушійної сили і за середовищем, у якому відбувається рух* (з наук.-попул. літ.).

Comment: While we may often call a specific car/bike/whatever, *транспорт*, that meaning isn't included in the article you are linking to.  The closest in that regard is "4. Вантажне судно морського флоту", but of course it refers to a very specific kind of vehicle. *Транспорт* in the general meaning of "**a** vehicle" isn't in the dictionary.  This is not to invalidate the usage you are suggesting.  I just think people might be confused, because they might see the link as a confirmation of the usage when in actual fact that specific meaning is neither in the quoted portion, nor in the entire article.

Comment: канцеляризм! Great word, thank you.  And yeah, it sounds like транспорт is not exactly vehicle but serves a similar function in most contexts where you'd need it.

Comment: Is there no cognate of the Polish 'Pojazd'?

Comment: @Spencer As I can see, [_pojazd_](https://wsjp.pl/haslo/do_druku/1363/pojazd) is from [_jeździć_](https://wsjp.pl/haslo/do_druku/32696/jezdzic) which is from _*ězditi_. If speak about Ukrainian then _ě → ї_, and Ukrainian has a word [_поїзд_](http://sum.in.ua/s/pojizd) which is a cognate, and already means _a train_.

Comment: @stegetsj: A vehicle is a thing.  The word *транспорт* applies to a group, not a single thing.  You could ask, "Скільки в тебе транспорт**у**?" ("Дві машини.") But you wouldn't ask, "Скільки в тебе транспорт**ів**?" In this sense it's a collective noun, hence not used in plural, hence not an exact equivalent of "vehicle". It's countable in other senses but not when speaking about vehicles in general.

Comment: @AndriyM Ehm… It isnʼt argument, because: 1) For example, Ukrainian doesnʼt a singular noun for _a door_, but _двері_ is _a door_. Therefore applying to a group or a thing isnʼt important.

Comment: @AndriyM 2) _Транспорт_ can be in plurar, and has such usage: [скільки транспортів](https://lib.chmnu.edu.ua/pdf/monograf/15/12.pdf), [скільки транспортів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Операція_«П'єдестал»), [скільки транспортів](https://hromadske.radio/podcasts/zustrichi/my-bil-she-doslidzhuvaly-vbyvts-a-ne-zhertv-istorychna-monohrafiia-pro-tabir-smerti-u-belzhytsi). Where source are: education material, kinda again but writed by anyone, news. So, you can say _Скільки маєш транспортів_ but, yeah, _скільки маєш транспорту_ is more common.

Comment: Other usages: [Leipzig](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=транспортів), [Grak](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance%3Fcorpname=grac15&tab=basic&keyword=транспортів&showresults=1).

Comment: I never said the word *транспорт* can't be plural *at all*, I only said it can't when you are talking about vehicles generally (which is what the question is about).  However, I'm beginning to think I was wrong saying that the dictionary didn't cover the meaning "a vehicle".  *Засіб перевезення*, as mentioned in the dictionary article, probably does mean exactly just that, a single means of transportation.  The explanation in your update makes sense to me, so I stand corrected, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting that nobody here mentioned just *машина*

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle)

> A vehicle is a **machine** *[in Ukrainian literally **машина**]*

And since the most used types of machines to transport people and cargo are cars,  minivans and trucks, ironically in Ukrainian when we mean any of these types of vehicles, in day-to-day life we just say ***машина*** [in English literally *machine*]

---

As to comment by *[@weronika](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/6953/is-vehicle-really-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1-do-people-say-that/7059#comment12251_6953)* about Ukrainian police: yes, they never say *"Вийдіть з транспортного засобу!* - they mostly say *"Вийдіть з **машини**!"* or sometimes *"Вийдіть з **авто(мобіля)**!"*

Comment: I heard *машина* only for land-type vehicles. But [one dictionary](http://sum.in.ua/s/mashyna) says otherwise: << 3. Транспортний засіб (автомобіль, танк, літак і т. ін.), що рухається завдяки якомусь механізмові. *заст.* Поїзд, паровоз. >>, so seems itʼs possibe.

Answer (score 1):

"транспортний засіб" can be literally translated as "method of transportation" or "means of transportation".

Vehicle could be translated as such only in a very specific context, e.g. in a customs form.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! How would you translate vehicle in a less bureaucratic context?

Comment: Sorry, I can only read Ukrainian. On the other hand, the answer from stegetsj expanded to include what I said here, so my answer is moot now.